# BulkButtonWidget in Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2

I am using BulkButtonWidget button to perform operations on mulitple records in Yii2 uding Ajax(johnitvn\ajaxcrud).
The problem is that when i remove `data-confirm-title` and
`data-confirm-message` The PKIDs of grid records does not come into post request.
Following is my code Where am i mistaking ?!

```
        BulkButtonWidget::widget([
                        'buttons'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">/i>&nbsp; Delete All',
                            ["bulk-delete"] ,
                            [
                                "class"=>"btn btn-danger btn-xs",
                                'role'=>'modal-remote-bulk',
                                'data-confirm'=>false,
                                //'data-method'=>false,// for overide yii data api
                                'data-request-method'=>'post',
                                'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                                'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to delete this item'
                            ]),
                    ])
```